# iPhone - Provisioning profiles and app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, provisioning

I decided to submit a new version of my app after about 5 months.
I went to provisioning profile and noticed that my certificate is missing.

Every app store provisioning profile is linked to my certificate, and since the certificate is missing i cannot download my provisioning profiles.

What is the solution here?
Is it possible to submit a new certificate and relate my provisioning profiles to the new certificate?

Comment: @Close voters: Please share what you think makes this question off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, generate a new certificate, 
then edit your provisioning profiles to select the new one in the *Certificates* section.

In your projects, make sure your new profiles are selected in the *Code signing* property.